# Converting a Matalab 60000x10 array to 60000x1 or 1x60000

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization, reduction

With a 2D array of size 60000 rows, 10 columns
I have the array as follows

```
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
.......
```

Any row will contain only a single '1'

I have to reduce this to a row or column vector that shows the index at which we had a 1. For example, for the above shown rows, we must end up with

`[6,1,10...]` uptil the 60,000th value.

How can I do this in Matlab without loops?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:**
A more efficient way is using matrix multiplication:

```
idx = a * (1:size(a,2)).'
```

**Previous answer**:

try this:

```
 a=[...
 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [r ,~]=find(a.')
```

using [Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293881/divakar) 's **benchmark**:

```
------------------- With FIND
Elapsed time is 1.55641 seconds.
------------------- With MAX
Elapsed time is 0.703054 seconds.
------------------- With MTIMES
Elapsed time is 0.266676 seconds.
```

Comment: Matrix multiplication! Nice.

Comment: @Divakar In a post I learned from you that multiplication is very efficient

Answer (score 6):

You can use `max` -

```
[~,idx] = max(a,[],2)
```

**Runtime test on `60000 x 10` array**

Benchmarking code -

```
% Setup input array
a = zeros(60000,10);
idx = randi(size(a,2),1,size(a,1));
a(sub2ind(size(a),1:size(a,1),idx)) = 1;

% Timing code
disp('------------------- With FIND')
tic,for i = 1:500,[r,~]=find(a.');end, toc

disp('------------------- With MAX')
tic,for i = 1:500,[~,idx] = max(a,[],2);end, toc
```

Timings -

```
------------------- With FIND
Elapsed time is 4.267364 seconds.
------------------- With MAX
Elapsed time is 1.353760 seconds.
```

Comment: [_"Interesting and smart approach!"_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28188788/2338750). =)

Comment: @StewieGriffin haha well max has its own benefits! :)